# implementing Volatility Managed Portfolios

Tags: volatility, portfolio-management

How to I calculate the value of c in the vol-managed equation specified by [Moreira & Muir](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2659431) *Volatilty Managed Portfolios* (2016) Equation 1?

Portfolio return in month t+1 =$$\frac{c}{RV_t^2}f_{t+1}$$

where $RV^2_t$ is the Realized variance over the past month , $f_{t+1}$ is the factor return in the next month.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Volatility Managed Strategies](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42947/implementing-volatility-managed-strategies)

Comment: Could you please add some more information here? "C" of some 2 author paper that it not linked ... hard to follow this question ..

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple "how to do it" answer.

Run the Volatility Managed Strategy over some historical period using an initial guess for $c$, say $c_0=0.05$. I will call this the Trial Run.

Compute the standard deviation of the strategy returns $\sigma_0$ and the standard deviation of the buy and hold returns $\sigma_{BH}$ over the same period.

Now run the Volatility Managed Strategy again over the same period but using $c=\frac{\sigma_{BH}}{\sigma_0}c_0$. This is the final run; you can check that the standard deviation of the VMS will be exactly equal to the standard deviation of buy and hold. And you are finished.